# Upgrade to studio 3.0 is crashing my app with dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass

Tags: android, android-studio, android-launcher

This is just happening after a migration from studio 2.x to studio 3.0 with android 4.4. Android 6 runs fine.
I googled this issue but didn't find crisp response. Just a particular app has this behavior. I have other apps which are fine.

The update process has broken something but what? Why is it impacting android 4.x only?

I tried clean sync, rebuild,restart studio, restart tablet, ...

here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.narb.test"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionName '3.2'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        versionNameSuffix '-9-nov-2017'
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 53
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.5.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
}
```

and the logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.narb.test/com.narb.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.narb.test.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.narb.test-29.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.narb.test-29, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.narb.test.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.narb.test-29.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.narb.test-29, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.narb.test">

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/networksafe"
        android:label="test"
        android:logo="@drawable/networksafe"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".vpn.services"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.Net.Services"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Settings"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.About" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.History" />

        <service
            android:name=".Socket"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service
            android:name=".ServiceMonitoring"
            android:exported="false" />


        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity android:name=".Activities.RateMe"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash was due to this line in build.gradle:

multiDexEnabled true

Once I removed this line the crash was gone.

I don't know why 2.3 has put this line originally but what is sure is that studio 3.0 made sdk 18 and below crash.

Answer (score 1):

Run the Gradle clean command  then do the File -> Invalidate caches & restart. For me it solves the problem

Comment: gradle clean: you mean duild->clean?

Comment: try from gradle perspective app->tasks->build->clean

Comment: I can't find an app menu?

Comment: nice try but it's crashing the same way. just to be sure: I did the clean (from the gradle window) then ivaldate caches & restart and run?

Comment: try with different build tool version. for me it solves

Comment: what do you mean by different build tool version?

Comment: instead of 26.0.2 just try 26.0.0 or 25. once build succeded then revert it back

Comment: already tried: version 18 and below have the problem. who cares about the old devices ;))

Comment: oh oh... below jelly bean it is differerent . check the app compat

Comment: it is a combination of something specific in my app (because I have other apps running fine on 4.4) and android studio 3.0 migration procedure. And this is really painful!!!

Comment: Some restriction in app compat lib.. try with normal activity

Comment: where did you see that?

Comment: I found it! that was the multidex line in the build.gradle :) Many thanks for your help and support

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you don't need multidex, then disabling it is the right solution. If you need it in the future, follow the instructions linked below to use the MultiDexApplication.

For context, there are two types of multidex, legacy and native. For devices API 21 and above, the platform just reads multiple dex files directly from the APK.

For devices before API 21, there is the multidex support library that patches the classloader to add in the extra dex files as part of an Application class. Anything that can be loaded before this happens needs to be in the main dex, and you need to use MultiDexApplication (or a subclass, or call MultiDex.install(this) from your Application onAtttachBaseContext)

Android studio 3.0 switched to creating the minimal main dex for debug builds, that is, only keeping the smallest set of files in the main dex. This is for build performance and to make these crashes reproducible, rather than it being luck if a class was included in the main dex or not.

In your case, your app fit in one dex in 2.3, but in 3.0 with the new minimal main dex behavior, that class was not in the main dex. However because you are not using the MultiDexApplication, the classloader is never patched, so the classes in the secondary dex file cannot be loaded.

For more information see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: it took me a day to find that I did not need it. I know it's tough to test every scenario but studio 2.3 created the gradle. I didn't kow what multidex was for. Upgrading studio (very nice tool) to a major release is always a task that you do while shaking... nice tie btw :)